# Qt/C++ - confused about caller/callee, object ownership

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a GUI to manipulate a robot arm. The location of the arm can be described by 6 floats (describing the positions of the various arm joints.

The interface consists of a QGraphicsView with a diagram of the arm (which can be clicked to change the arm position - adjusting the 6 floats). The interface also has 6 lineEdit boxes, to also adjust those values separately.

When the graphics view is clicked, and when the line edit boxes are changed, I'd like the line edit boxes / graphics view to stay in synchronisation.

This brings me to confusion about how to store the 6 floats, and trigger events when they're updated. My current idea is this:

- The robot arm's location should be represented by a class, RobotArmLocation. Objects of this class then have methods such as obj.ShoulderRotation() and obj.SetShoulderRotation().
- The MainWindow has a single instance of RobotArmLocation.

Next is the bit I'm more confused about, how to join everything up. I am thinking:

- The MainWindow has a ArmLocationChanged slot. This is signalled whenever the location object is changed.
- The diagram class will have a SetRobotArmLocation(RobotArmLocation &loc). When the diagram is changed, it's free to change the location object, and fire a signal to the ArmLocationChanged slot.
- Likewise, changing any of the text boxes will fire a signal to that ArmLocationChanged slot. The slot then has code to synchronise all the elements.

This kind of seems like a mess to me, does anyone have any other suggestions? I've also thought of the following, does it have any merrit?

- The RobotArmLocation class has a ValueChanged slot, the diagram and textboxes can use that directly, and bypass the MainWindow directly (seems cleaner?)

thanks for any wisdom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for really simple cases (e.g. a label that shows the value of a slider) my experience has been to stay away from inter-component signal/slot connections inside Qt Designer. Rather, have the component firing the signal of interest connect to a slog defined in the top level QWidget class you're subclassing (i.e. `QMainWidow`, etc... let's just call it the `Form` class). You can also go the other way: if you have a custom signal in the `Form` class, you can connect it with Qt Designer to one of the public widget slots.

To be specific using your example:

1. I'm going to assume that you have subclassed `QMainWindow` and `QGraphicsView`. Let's call the subclasses `RobotMainWindow` and `RobotView`.
2. `RobotMainWindow` contains the `QLineEdit` fields and `RobotView`. The way you specify `RobotView` in Qt Designer is to insert a `QWidget` and use the *Promote to...* feature to tell Qt that the `QWidget` should be replaced at compile time with your custom `RobotView`.
3. Name the `QLineEdit` fields `edit1`, `edit2`...`edit6`.
4. In the Qt Designer *signal/slot editor* define slots in `RobotMainWindow` to be called when the value in a `QLineEdit` changes. There are some more elegant ways of doing this, but for simplicity let's say you define 6 slots named `setValue1(float)`, `setValue2(float)`, etc.
5. In the **source code** for `RobotMainWindow`, go declare and define these slots, such that they update your arm, shoulder, whatever.
6. Also in the source code, define a signal `valueChanged()` (or multiple for each field, your choice). Have the slots you defined `emit valueChanged()`.
7. Back in Qt Designer you can now link the appropriate signal from each `QLineEdit` to the corresponding slot in `RobotMainWindow`.
8. Back in the *signal/slot editor* add the `valueChanged()` signal to the `RobotMainWindow` (so Qt Designer knows about it). Connect this signal to a new slot in `RobotView`, using the procedure above, so it can update the rendering.
9. Repeat all of this for handling changes from `RobotView` to the editing fields (via `RobotMainWindow`.

In short, I think you'll find everything more straight-forward if your route the signals through your `Form` subclass (which I think of as the *Controller* in MVC parlance).